# pip install -r requirements delete all packages on failure

Tags: python, pip

I have a very long requirements.txt file and everytime a single package fails installing from pip install -r requirements.txt and I relaunch the same command again, it will restart from the very beginning of the list.

Is there any option to save the successful installs and not start it all over from scratch (some are very long to compile).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure it's not failing on the first package? What sort of failure? Can you paste the error? Can you paste the requirements.txt file?

Comment: When a package is already installed, pip just says `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): packagename>=version in /some/path`. It doesn't reinstalls it

Comment: I'm talking about the situation where pip installs a lot of packages inside the requirements.txt file, and when getting to the package that fails, and relaunching the command pip install -r requirements.txt, it restarts from the very beginning (I can identify the same packages that got previously installed).
It looks like I have issue with pip install scipy numpy (but my question is more generic)

Comment: What version of pip do you have? It's normal that it starts from the beginning though - newer versions of pip should have better caching to reduce the time to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, it was resolved for me by manually installing the libraries that had the most dependencies with `sudo apt-get install`.

If you manually go for :

- sudo apt-get install python-scipy
- sudo apt-get install python-numpy
- sudo apt-get install pandas

Once these large packages which have many dependencies are installed using `apt-get`, installing the rest via `pip` will be easy and will go smoothly.

N.B. - Use `pip3` and `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy` commands if you're using Python3.

Comment: I resolved it by running sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib (or python-scipy).

Comment: The dependencies are downloaded and installed on the `sudo apt-get install` directly as well though. Anyway glad it worked for you !